# importar metodos de uma DLL Bematech não gerenciada c#

Tags: c#, interoperabilidade

Estou precisando utilizar uma dll fornecida pela Bematech com funcionalidades de uma impressora não fiscal. O exemplo que disponibilizaram traz o seguinte código:

```
[DllImport("MP2032.dll")]
public static extern int ConfiguraModeloImpressora(int model);
```

O programa gera a seguinte exceção:

> Additional information: Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um
>   programa com um formato incorreto. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Acreditando que o problema poderia ser na dll criei um novo projeto para gerar uma dll exportável. Retornou o mesmo erro. Já li vários post's e artigos e não compreendo por que meu código não funciona.

Comment: A DLL utilizada corresponde a arquitetura do teu executável? (32 ou 64 bits)

Comment: Sim Bruno, 32 bits.

Comment: Tenta seguir a dica proposta neste link (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/216a765f-3082-4fd0-bdd7-b90707daa393/erro-dll-daruma) acho que pode te ajudar.

Comment: @tiagocosta confere se realmente seu projeto nas propriedades -> Build -> Platform Target está x86. as vezes que tive esse problema foi por causa de não estar x86.

Comment: Obrigado Bruno Bermann e Pablo Vargas, deu certo.